# why char* takes 4 bytes instead of 1 byte

Tags: c

I wrote a program to find endianness of a system. It doesnt work as the pointer value is 0xffffffef instead of 0xef. Why is the pointer value 0xffffffef? I declared it as a char* which should take only 1 byte.
I can fix the problem by *ptr&0xff but I don't know why the pointer value is 4bytes instead of 1byte.

```
int main() {

uint32_t value = 0xdeadbeef;
char *ptr;
ptr = (char*)&value;

if(*ptr == 0xef){
    printf("it is little endianeness");
}

printf(" 0x%x *ptr\n",);

}
```

Comment: Try `uint8_t *ptr` instead of `char *ptr`. That should make the `if` statement work as expected.

Comment: @user3386109 the problem is not with the `if`, that works fine. The problem is with the `printf`

Comment: @RemyLebeau the problem is not with the printf. user3386109 is right.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 0xEF (239) it's unsigned and char is signed, why the problem isn't with if?

Comment: The problem is with _both_.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Works fine in what way? A reasonable interpretation of the code would be that the `printf("it is little endianeness")` should be called on a little endian system. But it most certainly won't be called on a typical implementation (8-bit signed char, two's complement).

Comment: `0xffffffef` is not the value of the pointer. It's the value of the character, after being converted and reinterpreted. And the code in your question will not compile. Read this: [mre] Specifically, this: `printf(" 0x%x *ptr\n",);` was probably meant to be: `printf(" 0x%x\n", *ptr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf(" 0x%x *ptr\n",);`

should be

`printf(" 0x%x\n", *ptr);`

but the reason it prints out as `0xffffffef` instead of `0xef` is because `%x` interprets the input value as an `unsigned int` and so the char value is first **sign extended** to match the size of an `int`. `0xef` is binary `11101111`, notice the high bit is set. When extended as a signed value, that high bit gets repeated in the added bits:

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11101111`

aka `0xffffffef`.

To avoid *sign* extending, cast the char value to an **unsigned** value first so it then gets *zero* extended instead:

`00000000 00000000 00000000 11101111`

aka `0x000000ef`, or just `0xef` when leading zeros are omitted:

`printf(" 0x%x\n", (unsigned char) *ptr);`

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can use `%hhx` instead, which interprets the input value as an `unsigned char`, so you can avoid the explicit typecast:

`printf(" 0x%hhx\n", *ptr);`

Comment: Slight correction: `%x` takes `unsigned int`.

Comment: "%hhx" can be used instead of ugly casting.